# Flask pagination help in Python

Tags: python, mysql, flask, pagination

I'm trying to create a button in my HTML that will go to the next/previous page when the button is clicked. I've tried pagination and peewee but didn't seem to get it to work.

Here is my app:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request, json
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'example'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'example'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'example'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'fund_raiser'
mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/funds/pages/', defaults={'page':0})
@app.route('/funds/pages/<int:page>')
def fund_pages(page):
    perpage = 5
    first_page = page*perpage
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from fund_table limit "+str(first_page)+", "+str(perpage)+";", mysql.connection.commit())
    data = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('funds.html', data=data)
```

Where do I add the href tag in my html page? What is the correct variable to use?

Comment: This is vulnerable to sql injection. Please never take data from the user and send it straight to your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy with the `url_for()` function.
You can call the name of the function for the route, and pass it a variable.

`href="{{ url_for('fund_pages', page=page_num) }}"`

Where `page_num` is the page number.

To get the page number dynamically, you can simple add or subtract 1 from the current page number. For example, you could store `page_prev = current_page - 1` and `page_next = current_page + 1`.

You can these pass those variables to the `url_for` function as the `page` parameter.

Example:

```
# in fund_pages()
prev_page = page - 1
next_page = page + 1
return render_template('template.hmtl', next_page=next_page, prev_page=prev_page)

# in the template
<a href="{{ url_for('fund_pages', page=prev_page) }}">Previous</a>
<a href="{{ url_for('fund_pages', page=next_page) }}">Next</a>
```

Comment: Should I modify something in the app.py file? because that code didnt work for me. it gives me an unifentified variable.

Comment: @xiholac761 can you post the full error message please?

Comment: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError

UndefinedError: 'page_num' is undefined

Comment: @xiholac761 yes, that was the variable I used as a placeholder for the page number you want to redirect the user to. For page 1, have `page=1` etc.

Comment: @xiholac761 I have ammended the post to have a better example.